# Multiple Magnific popup in loop only showing content of last item

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm using this function to show youtube videos in a lightbox through Magnific Popup. I get the `id` of `.video-youtube` links to create a dynamic `iframe` for any link.

In this page I have 3 different links and the problem is that the lightbox only shows the last video instead of changing it dynamically depending on which link is clicked. Any hint would be appreciated.

```html
<a id="siTrd7uucW" class="video-youtube" href="#">Click to view video</a>
<a id="reFad8ug77" class="video-youtube" href="#">Click to view video</a>
<a id="sghrd7tu99" class="video-youtube" href="#">Click to view video</a>
```

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".video-youtube").each(function() {
      var id = this.id;
      $(window).load(function() {
        $('.video-youtube').magnificPopup({
          items: {
            src: $('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'),
            type: 'inline'
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the `window.load` is not necessary. You're running in a document.ready handler, so `window.load` will already have fired.

With regard to the issue it's because you're selecting all `$('.video-youtube')` elements in the loop. Use `$(this)` to *only* refer to the current instance:

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $(".video-youtube").each(function() {
      $(this).magnificPopup({
        items: {
          src: $('<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + this.id + '?autoplay=1" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'),
          type: 'inline'
        }
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.